# A question is closed and its new version is answered

Tags: discussion

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114288/nullreferenceexception-in-linq) was marked as duplicate, 10 minutes later he wrote the same question with a different title and it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114629/how-to-do-a-null-check-in-linq#38114629). Was it a bad decision to mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: No, you can mark the new version as a duplicate as well.

Comment: I did that already.. lol

Comment: The presence of answers says nothing. The people who posted the answers may not be aware of any duplicates.

Comment: @Lundin but they should.

Comment: The King is dead. Long live the King.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's unrealistic to expect every user to either 1) be aware of the content of every single question on the site, so they can instinctively know when any new question is a duplicate, or 2) research every question they want to answer, and scour every previously-asked question that might be related to find any possible duplicates, before posting an answer.

Comment: @JustinTime: actually, it's _entirely_ realistic to expect every user considering writing an answer to first do at least a minimal search on the topic, i.e. copy/paste the question title and search for that. Yes, it is still possible for duplicates to slip through, but the bulk of the problem is that most people answering don't stop to think for even the slightest moment whether they are about to answer a question that's already been answered before.

Comment: @PeterDuniho While that's a good idea, as you said, it doesn't guarantee that they'll catch every duplicate.  While this is likely only because we parse things differently, I read "but they should [be aware of any duplicates]" as meaning that anyone that posts an answer should be aware of _any_ duplicate questions, not just common ones.  That's what I was replying to, the expectation that before posting an answer, a user should first guarantee that the question isn't a duplicate of _any_ previously-existing question.

Comment: ...This may be because I sometimes tend to take things too far, and/or misread things in a way that implies that they should be taken too far, though.

Comment: To add insult to injury, the referenced question and answer is a classic example of how screwed up SO is a lot of the time. Not only did a 95K user answer a question that never should have been answered, they didn't actually solve the problem, and yet in spite of both of those issues, got FOUR upvotes? That's just insane.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "it's entirely realistic to expect every user..." Hmm, they are not. I wonder how prevalent the undesired behavior is, even a small percent of users who ask first and search later will clog things up? I wonder how users can be (easily) trained or if the site can help more, maybe by offering search results similar to the question before you can click [Post]?

Comment: @JustinTime and your comments is an example how the *meta* site works. You are not interested in the problem in question, you are interested in an argument.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not true.  I'm not interested in arguing, I'm solely pointing out that it is indeed unrealistic to expect everyone to spend an hour making sure the question has never been asked & answered before, instead of spending the same or less time actually _answering_ it.  If the question is common, then yes, it's realistic to expect them to check for duplicates.  If it's an odd or obscure case that one wouldn't expect to come up frequently, if at all, it's usually better to assume that the asker already checked for answers.

Comment: Both questions have now been deleted.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Vote to close it again, either as a duplicate of the first, or of the duplicate the original was closed as; preferably the latter, if possible.

You may also leave a note to the OP that they shouldn't be asking the same question twice, they should be updating their first question to include any new information that further explains the problem; and why it isn't a duplicate, if applicable.

Example:

> Please don't ask `[the same question](link to first)` twice; update your existing one with new information.

Comment: Umm ... The "marked as duplicate" info box explicitly says "If those answers do not fully address your question, please **ask a new question.**" Nothing in there about updating the marked-as-duplicate question with new information.

Comment: @R.M. - That info box doesn't mean you should re-ask the exact same question without new information... but you raise a good point..

Comment: @R.M. - Posted a [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327202/1324033) on meta based on your comment.

Answer (score -10):

Just relax. That's the way Stack Overflow is intended to work - to let people gain their reputation points by means of answering duplicated questions.

Think that other ten celebrated zillions of questions are all unique? Come on, face the facts.

Comment: Your cynicism is amusing but unhelpful.