# Ask a new question if not a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, notifications

I was [recently reminded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327158/a-question-is-closed-and-its-new-version-is-answered/327159?noredirect=1#comment363140_327159) that the help text when a question is closed as a duplicate states that you should ask a new question

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

Why is it encouraged that you should create a new question instead of edit your existing question to further clarify it?

A post on the main meta, [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled), has an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/298072) that states

> If you think a question is related, but not a duplicate, it's a good idea to edit the question to add a note explaining the difference.

So why the inconsistency? Which is correct? Should the close reason message be changed?

Comment: I think this should be tagged support, but wasn't entirely sure that was your intent so instead of just changing it, I left this comment. Your move. :)

Comment: The community can still answer support questions, the main difference is whether the response should be a discussion on the messaging in general or an explanation of the difference (were there a valid explanation).

Comment: Not sure if it really maters if you post a new question and explain in there why it is not a duplicate or edit the closed one.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The difference is in the trajectory if it turns out the user is persistently mistaken in their idea of what is and isn't a duplicate (a common problem). If they ask a new question every time they disagree with a dupe closure, we'll be flooded with their questions. But if they have to edit and wait for reopening, there's no such potential, and the site is not forced to rely on the self-control of highly-inexperienced and impatient askers.

Answer (score 16):

Those are two different situations. If you agree with the dupe closure, then

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

If you need more information, you can comment on the answers over there or try to get the information by asking a new question.

However,

> If you think a question is related, but not a duplicate, it's a good idea to edit the question to add a note explaining the difference.

Note the potential difference between the problem you have and the problem you described in your question: The dupe need only solve the latter.

If the dupe does answer the question you asked, but does not solve your problem -> new question in which you ask about your actual problem.

Comment: So you're saying you should ask a new question if the duplicate was correct in order to clarify some details, edit a question if the duplicate didn't solve the problem? That kind of make sense, but then I'd argue that both of those situations should be explained within the help text of the duplicate message.

Comment: @Sayse Probably yes, though one would have to evaluate how much needless noob FAQ would end up in the reopen queue due to this.